# Usages of logarithmic mean in optimization

Tags: optimization, applications, lambert-w, wright-omega

I have recently learned about the [logarithmic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_mean)

$$\frac{x-y}{\ln(x)-\ln(y)},\quad x,y > 0.$$

It is used a lot in chemical engineering optimization models e.g. see slide 15 of [Developing spatial branch & bound solvers](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~rmisener/MINLPSolver_Tutorial.pdf).

But I wonder if anyone else has come across the logarithmic mean elsewhere in optimization?

[Rao and Dey (2014)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/78f0/2cf8229b44293fbd1e2182e8e1a46cd3a2c6.pdf)<sup>1</sup> mention a relation to the Lambert $W$ function that I find interesting. [Borwein and Lindstrom (2016)](https://www.carma.newcastle.edu.au/resources/jon/WinOpt.pdf)<sup>2</sup> discuss about the usage of the Lambert $W$ function in optimization.

PS. The blog post  [Logarithmic mean temperature difference requires yet another cone?](https://themosekblog.blogspot.com/2019/06/logarithmic-mean-temperature-difference.html) discusses whether you can build a conic representation.

---

<sub>References</sub>

<sub>[1] Rao, M., Dey, A. (2014). Scope of the Logarithmic Mean. *The Australian Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications.* 11(1):1-10.</sub>

<sub>[2] Lindstrom, S. B., Borwein, J. M. (2016). Meetings with Lambert $W$ and Other Special Functions in Optimization and Analysis.</sub>

Comment: I just heard Logarithmic Mean Divisia Index (LMDI). I am not sure if it is completely related..

Comment: Also a very old paper: downloads.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/1982/718951.pdf

This paper gives some relevant references [2-5]

Comment: @Henrik A. Friberg Maybe someone more clever than me can figure out how to formulate logarithmic mean with "existing" cones, by using some combination of CVXQUAD (quantum entropy and logm related) functions (implemented in CVX) https://github.com/hfawzi/cvxquad  . I've not succeeded, but it seems there's a great deal of expressive power w/ these functions. So maybe some clever choice of matrices and combination of functions?

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 I believe "lambert" tag you removed refers to "Lambert W" function, which is conic representable using the exponential cone - see pp. 126-127 of https://perso.uclouvain.be/francois.glineur/files/theses/Chares-PhD-thesis-2007.pdf  (for instance in CVX, YALMIP, CVXPY and similar optimization modeling systems , and with Mosek, SCS, ECOS solvers). Maybe "LambertW" tag? I can assure you that the OP is familiar with the reference I have, because he posted it in the CVX Forum. in 2017 at http://ask.cvxr.com/t/lambert-function/4338/3

Comment: @MarkL.Stone yeah, I know, I just thought it seemed too specialized to warrant a tag — that it might end up with only the one question ever. But sounds from your comment that it comes up not infrequently? If so I can roll back the edit — or change to lambda-w if you think that’s better.

Comment: It could come up again. It has a way pf appearing in probability, statistics, and other places - see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lambert+W . And it's pretty cool that it is conic representable. I suspect the OP included it because Lambert W, and how it is conic representable, has some similarity with and might have some bearing on logarithmic mean.  If capital letters are not allowed in tags, I guess lambert-w is best.

Comment: Another more "accessible" reference:  Section 5.2.9 of "Mosek Modeling Cookbook" Release 3.1 https://docs.mosek.com/MOSEKModelingCookbook-letter.pdf

Comment: The Lambert is an up and coming function. I have now added a link to by late Borwein about the Lambert function and optimization.

Comment: In the interest of confusion minimization for readers, I will note that one of the links you provided https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/78f0/2cf8229b44293fbd1e2182e8e1a46cd3a2c6.pdf refers to Lambert’s Omega function, which is an alternate name for the Lambert W function

Comment: I'm actually just adding lambertw (i.e. automatic expcone conversion) to YALMIP as we need it in a small project.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks for fixing, all.

Comment: I know I am bit sloppy with the word Lambert. I use Lambert to mean all functions closely related with Lambert function. For instance I include Omega Wright.

Comment: I added a tag for wright-omega .

Comment: Dreams do come true. New paper published today "Computing the Lambert W function in arbitrary-precision complex interval arithmetic" https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11075-019-00678-x in the journal "Numerical Algorithms"

Answer (score 14):

> But I wonder if anyone else has come across the logarithmic mean elsewhere in optimization?

[Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization) is simply the selection of a best element (with regard to some criterion) from some set of available alternatives. (From: "[The Nature of Mathematical Programming](https://web.archive.org/web/20140305080324/http://glossary.computing.society.informs.org/index.php?page=nature.html)", by George B. Dantzig).

The logarithmic mean has a relationship with other means as follows:

From [Long and Chu (2011)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268671183_Optimal_generalized_logarithmic_mean_bounds_for_the_geometric_combination_of_arithmetic_and_harmonic_means)<sup>1</sup>,

> Let $A(a,b)=(a+b)/2$, $I(a,b)=1/e(b^b/a^a)^{1/(b−a)}$, $L(a,b)=(b−a)/(\ln b−\ln a)$, $G(a,b)=\sqrt{ab}$ and $H(a,b)=2ab/(a+b)$ be the arithmetic, identric, **logarithmic**, geometric, and harmonic **means** of two positive numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a\ne b$,
>   respectively. Then
>   \begin{align}\min\{a, b\}&< H(a, b)< G(a, b) = L_{−2}(a, b)< L(a, b) = L_{-1}(a, b)\\&< I(a, b) = L_0(a, b)< A(a, b) = L_1(a, b)<\max\{a, b\}.\end{align}

See also [Pittenger (1987)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X8790309X)<sup>2</sup> for a discussion of logarithmic means (page 286), and the [Glivenko-Cantelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem) (p. 287). Further resources include the [Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality#Building_CDF_bands) and building [CDF bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDF-based_nonparametric_confidence_interval#CDF_bounds) from Wikipedia.

A [logarithmic relationship](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/logarithmic) occurs when the logs of two variables plotted against each other create a straight line. A semilogarithmic relationship is when there is linearity when only one of the variables is scaled as a logarithm.

For further reading on the (weighted) logarithmic mean, see p. 885-886 of [Neuman (1994)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/238389878_The_Weighted_Logarithmic_Mean)<sup>3</sup>.

---

In [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) the right-hand predictor side of the equation must be linear with the left-hand outcome side of the equation. You must [test for linearity](http://euclid.psych.yorku.ca/SCS/sasmac/boxtid.html) in the logit (in logistic regression the logit is the outcome side). This is commonly done with the [Box-Tidwell transformation](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1677374)<sup>4</sup>.

- Add to the logistic model interaction terms which are the cross product of each independent times its natural logarithm $X\ln X$. If these terms are significant, then there is nonlinearity in the logit.

> "In the [logistic model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression), the log-odds (the logarithm of the odds) for the value labeled "1" is a linear combination of one or more independent variables ("predictors"); the independent variables can each be a binary variable (two classes, coded by an indicator variable) or a continuous variable (any real value). The corresponding probability of the value labeled "1" can vary between 0 (certainly the value "0") and 1 (certainly the value "1"), hence the labeling; the function that converts log-odds to probability is the logistic function, hence the name. The unit of measurement for the log-odds scale is called a logit, from logistic unit, hence the alternative names. Analogous models with a different sigmoid function instead of the logistic function can also be used, such as the probit model; the defining characteristic of the logistic model is that increasing one of the independent variables multiplicatively scales the odds of the given outcome at a constant rate, with each dependent variable having its own parameter; for a binary independent variable this generalizes the odds ratio.".

See also [Logistic regression: Definition of the logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Logistic_function,_odds,_odds_ratio,_and_logit) from Wikipedia.

---

<sub>References</sub>

<sub>[1] Long, B-Y., Chu, Y-M. (2011). Optimal generalized logarithmic mean bounds for the geometric combination of arithmetic and harmonic means. *Journal of the Indonesian Mathematical Society.* 17(2):85–96.</sub>

<sub>[2] Pittenger, A. O. (1987). Limit theorems for logarithmic means. *Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications.* 123(1):281-291.</sub>

<sub>[3] Neuman, E. (1994). The Weighted Logarthmic Mean. *Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications.* 188(3):885-900.</sub>

<sub>[4] Joyce T., Donovan, J., Murphy, E. (2006). The application of the box-tidwell transformation in reliability modeling. *Annual Reliability and Maintainability Symposium.*</sub>